# :Python3 Tkinter Requests: Travamento temporário no get('url') com o modulo requests!

Tags: python, python-3.x, criptografia, tkinter, python-requests

É o seguinte criei um script para 'descriptografar' hash md5, porem quando insiro no Entry `21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3` que é `admin` e está contido na wordlist, ele trava toda vez ao chegar na linha do `b=get(f'url').content.decode().split()` a janela do tkinter fica travando até a requisição ser completa, ou seja, até jogar a wordlist na variavel , tem como esperar a requisição sem a janela travar..

```
from hashlib import md5
from requests import get
from tkinter import Button, Entry , Label , Tk ,END
root=Tk()

def test():  
    a=str(decry.get()).strip()
    if len(a)==32 or len(a)==40 or len(a)==64 and a.isdigit()==False and a.isalpha()==False and a.isalnum()==True:
        pass
    else:
        return
    c=0
    url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/danielmiessler/SecLists/master/Passwords/Common-Credentials/10-million-password-list-top-1000000.txt'
    b=get(f'url').content.decode().split()
    while(True):
        root.update()
        if str(md5(b[c].encode()).hexdigest())== a:
            decry.delete(0, END)
            decry.insert(0, b[c])
            but["text"]="Decrypter"
            break
        else:
            c+=1
            if c==len(b):
                break


root.geometry("390x120")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.title("Decry(hash(num)) v2.0")
lab1=Label(root, font="Arial 9 bold" , text="\n(Md5, Sha1 , Sha256) Todos os direitos reservados a Code Ghost.")
lab1.pack()
decry=Entry(root, width=40,font="Arial 12 bold")
decry.pack()
but=Button(root, text='Decrypter', command=test)
but.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: procure ser mais genérico e com isso mais claro. Apresentar um problema totalmente baseado em seu algorítimo não oferece beneficio algum a outros usuários. Descreva o problema com maiores detalhe e busque um título mais conciso, se possível.  Assim será mais fácil ajuda-lo.

Comment: Tem como fazer um [mcve]? O que seria "esperar sem travar"? O código abaixo desta linha depende do retorno, `wordlist`, então como seria o "sem travar" enquanto `wordlist` não possui um valor definido?

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta! Deixei mais verificável.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que essa única linha faz a solicitação e baixa o arquivo inteiro, assim, o tkinter não tem tempo de atualizar a interface, porque fica muito tempo sem chamar o `root.update()`.

Uma forma de amenizar o problema é baixar o arquivo linha a linha ao invés de baixá-lo inteiro de uma vez. Troque o código da linha que está travando até o final da função `test()` por esse código:

```
with get(url, stream=True) as r:
    for word in r.iter_lines()
        root.update()
        word = word.strip()
        if str(md5(word.encode()).hexdigest())== a:
            decry.delete(0, END)
            decry.insert(0, word)
            but["text"]="Decrypter"
            break
```

Outra vantagem desse método é que, ao encontrar a palavra que você quer, vai parar de baixar o arquivo, economizando tempo e rede.

Comment: Nossa.. impressionado! Eu nao sabia que dava pra fazer isso, muito obrigado!